# create a user defined function for sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk

I want to make a user defined function in sqlite for android, as I read earlier if you want to create the function using `sqlite3_create_function` you must do this throw the `NDK`, but you need to include the [SQLite C Library](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)  in the lib folder. but I have one question. If I include a SQLite C Library for 3.7 in my `lib` folder for example, do the function works probably if the targeting device uses a lower SQLite version ?

Comment: Are you attempting to mix the Java SQLite database APIs and a C SQLite library in order to create a user defined function?

Comment: There will be no problem if you are reading and writing your SQLite database only from C. Are you going to read / write it from Java too?